# Using Thymeleaf in a command line java application

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'd like to use Thymeleaf to populate HTML snippets which are used in a Google Earth KML file. The application that generates the KML can be used directly from the command line, with another java module providing a web interface. Is this possible without in involving an MVC framework? I am currently using Velocity to map variable data into velocity templates to generate HTML snippets but would much rather work with Thymeleaf so I can prototype the output more easily.

Comment: "_Is this possible without in involving an MVC framework?_" - Short answer is: Yes, this is possible. You can use Thymeleaf in a standard Java application (no web framework required). The application can populate Thymeleaf templates and generate rendered HTML output (as text). Create a [`TemplateEngine`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.12.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/TemplateEngine.html) and then use its [process()](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.12.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/TemplateEngine.html#process(java.lang.String,org.thymeleaf.context.IContext)) method.

Comment: You can follow the JavaDoc instructions or similar instructions in the [official tutorial](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#creating-and-configuring-the-template-engine). If you get stuck you can ask a specific question for your specific problem. As it stands, your current question is somewhat high-level and may be closed because of this.

Comment: Apart from all that, welcome! - don't forget to take the [tour] and read [ask] for suggestions on how to ask a good question for this site.

Comment: OK that's no a problem, I did spend some time searching for an answer, but if it is obvious then understand if closing this is the best option, thanks.